# Can't connect to testnet on Mist

Tags: mist

When I tried to switch to testnet on Mist through develop->network->testnet, I met this problem, like the picture below. What's the problem? How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to start your `geth` node first to connect to testnet, and then mist which will connect to the node. Instructions on starting `geth` for testnet Ropsten Revival are here:

https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten

Blockchain explorer is here: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/

You can even use https://www.myetherwallet.com/ as a web wallet for the Rposten.